# xhprof chart description

Tags: php, optimization, profiling, xhprof

For profiling, I have started to use XHprof. Nice tool! But, one question I can't answer by myself relates to chart content. Is there anyone who knows what color box and width of arrows on XHProf generated charts mean?

**UPDATED**
It was not last question, here is couple new:

- Why on chart could be two or more red squares but only one of it will be connected by  thick arrow with yellow squares ?
- What does it mean load:: in "Function name" column (on table mode view) ? is it means that PHP spent (cpu, mem etc) for loading that file ? Spent CPU time and Memory usage different from file to file, is it depends from filesize ? or content of file ? or both ? or something else ?
- What can you say (without detailes) when you'll see such charts ?

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7017985/Screenshots/h4kq.png
    https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7017985/Screenshots/r1bc.png

is it possible to figure out anything without details, just looking on these charts ?

Comment: No need to repeat your question multiple times :)

Answer (score 2):

- Red squares are just items that are taking a significant amount of the total time.  Yellow squares are the path the program took to get to them.  If you're trying to improve performance, look at the red squares first :)
- Looking at my examples, load:: is a method call to load a particular file, so yes, different calls would depend on the size of the file loaded.
- As above, look at the red squares first to improve performance.  On the second link, you may have some sql queries you can optimize.